# What is the equivalent of MySQL LOCATE to Bigquery?

Tags: mysql, sql, google-bigquery

So I have this query with `LOCATE` function:

```
SELECT TRIM(CASE WHEN store_name like "%|%" THEN LEFT(store_name, LOCATE('|', store_name) - 1) ELSE
                CASE WHEN store_name like "%,%" THEN LEFT(store_name, LOCATE(',', store_name) - 1) ELSE
                     CASE WHEN store_name like "% - %" THEN LEFT(store_name, LOCATE(' - ', store_name) - 1) ELSE
                         store_name
                     END
                END
             END)
```

Everything is working, but I need to change from MySQL to Bigquery now. When I tried to paste this query in Bigquery editor, I got an error: `Function not found: LOCATE at [3:76]`

Comment: `INSTR()` https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/string_functions#instr In MySQL INSTR and LOCATE differs in parameters order only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are different similar functions to Locate using BigQuery such as `REGEXP_EXTRACT`[1], as the `INSTR` [2], or `SUBSTR`[3] function.

[1]https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/legacy-sql#regularexpressionfunctions

[2]https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/string_functions#instr

[3]https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#substr

Answer (score 1):

Consider below approach (using [REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/string_functions#regexp_extract_all))

```
select regexp_extract_all(store_name, r'(.*?)(?:,| - |\|)')[offset(0)]
```

if applied to dummy data - output is as below

[image]